# Which part of process virtual memory layout does mmap() uses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The **mmap()** function shall establish a mapping between a process virtual address space and a device file or physical memory region.

A **process virtual memory layout** has the following sections:

[image]

Which region of *Process Virtual Address Space* does *mmap()* use for mapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mmap uses "unallocated memory".

Please note that the picture you drew is unlikely to be used on any UNIX system that is younger than about 30 years. UNIX *used* do have that memory layout in the early 70s, but the picture is much more complicated nowdays, especially when using shared libraries.

Answer (score 4):

To get an insight of what is happenning today, try (on Linux) the following command

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

on my machine, it gives now

```
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1850896                            /bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 1850896                            /bin/cat
00adc000-00afd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffe843ef000-7ffe84569000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 787567                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffe84569000-7ffe84769000 ---p 0017a000 08:01 787567                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffe84769000-7ffe8476d000 r--p 0017a000 08:01 787567                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffe8476d000-7ffe8476e000 rw-p 0017e000 08:01 787567                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffe8476e000-7ffe84773000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe84773000-7ffe84792000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 790578                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffe8495e000-7ffe84961000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe84990000-7ffe84992000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe84992000-7ffe84993000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 790578                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffe84993000-7ffe84994000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 790578                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffe84994000-7ffe84995000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdbaac000-7fffdbacd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffdbb66000-7fffdbb67000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

It shows the memory map of the process executing the `cat` command.

Comment: This goes into more detail http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-viewing-process-address-space-command/