# Virtual memory sections and memory mapping area

Tags: linux

As process has virtual memory which is copied into RAM during run time. As given in the previous post.

[Which part of process virtual memory layout does mmap() uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295510/which-part-of-process-virtual-memory-layout-does-mmap-uses)

[image]

I have following doubles :

1. If memory mapping is inside unallocated memory and it is inside process's virtual memory. As virtual memory helps to avoid one process to touch other process's virtual memory. Then how can memory mapping is used for Interprocess Communication(IPC)?
2. In OS like Linux, whether has each individual process separate section of heap, stack and memory mapping or all processes have one common section for heap, stack and MMAP?
   Example :
   if there are P1,P2 and P3 processes are running on linux OS. will all have common table as given in picture or each individual task have separate table to each section.
3. In 32 bit system, 2^32=4 gigabytes of virtual memory is possible and 1G byte is reserved for kernel and 3 gigabytes for userspace applications. can each individual process have up to 3 gigabytes of virtual memory or sum of all userspace applications size could be 3 gigabytes (i.e virtual memory size of (P1+P2+P3)<=3 gigabytes)?

--
Learner

Answer (score 2):

1. Using memory mapping for IPC works by mapping the same range of *physical* memory into two or more *virtual* address ranges in different processes. This works for communication because both processes are using the exact same memory cells (although they might "see" them differently, at different addresses). You change a value in one mapping, and it is instantly visible in the other mapping in a different process *because it is the very same memory*.
2. Every process has its own independent stack and heap. The OS does not care about that at all, it only cares about *pages*. The heap and the stack are things that are implemented by the application (via the runtime). When you call a function like `malloc`, the allocator in the runtime either returns a block that it already had reserved earlier or one that it has recylced (you called `free` earlier), or it asks the OS to reserve some more memory (`sbrk` or `mmap`). When you first access this memory, the OS sees a page fault and verifies that you are allowed to access this location (because you've reserved it) and then provides a valid page.
3. Every process can use (as in "reserve") the whole available address space (3GiB in your example). This does not interfere with any other process. Note that due to fragmentation and alignment, and because your executable and the stack take away a little bit, you will in practice not be able to allocate the full 3 GiB, but you can get close to it.
   All processes together can use as much virtual memory as is available on the system (physical RAM plus swap space), but they can only use as much as there is physical memory available *at the same time* (minus a little bit for this and that, like unpageable kernel memory and such).